# Need help isolating subset of value-pairs from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to isolate a small subset of key-value pairs from a large dictionary (date_vol_dict).

Given I have a list of VALUES of interest (from dictionary), how do I run through the main dictionary and pull the key-value pairs associated with each value_of_interest into a sub-dictionary?

```
values_of_interest_list = [338584400, 124297600, 55018300, 36316900, 34989200, 19653500, 13652600, 12924100, 11142500, 9126400]
date_vol_dict = {'2020-09-30': 338584400, '2020-10-01': 124297600, '2020-10-02': 55018300, '2020-10-05': 36316900, '2020-10-06': 90864000, '2020-10-07': 54672400, '2020-10-08': 34989200, '2020-10-09': 19653500, '2020-10-12': 20623600, '2020-10-13': 21847200, '2020-10-14': 13652600, '2020-10-15': 12924100, '2020-10-16': 11142500, '2020-10-19': 9126400, '2020-10-20': 11138200, '2020-10-21': 9190000, '2020-10-22': 17928600, '2020-10-23': 12618000, '2020-10-26': 23767300, '2020-10-27': 53695900, '2020-10-28': 30941700, '2020-10-29': 20515700, '2020-10-30': 19705500, '2020-11-02': 11677800, '2020-11-03': 21652800, '2020-11-04': 15783400, '2020-11-05': 48560400, '2020-11-06': 89977600, '2020-11-09': 60099000, '2020-11-10': 38078700, '2020-11-11': 47027900, '2020-11-12': 97904000, '2020-11-13': 76354800, '2020-11-16': 65326000, '2020-11-17': 116618500, '2020-11-18': 89957900, '2020-11-19': 56225400, '2020-11-20': 72104000, '2020-11-23': 84716300, '2020-11-24': 115468800, '2020-11-25': 202563700, '2020-11-27': 207834000, '2020-11-30': 137243000, '2020-12-01': 84539800, '2020-12-02': 149062100, '2020-12-03': 85634300, '2020-12-04': 56044100, '2020-12-07': 118463700, '2020-12-08': 124754300, '2020-12-09': 79634700, '2020-12-10': 57774800, '2020-12-11': 52764400, '2020-12-14': 44734500, '2020-12-15': 49273200, '2020-12-16': 44013400, '2020-12-17': 53829800, '2020-12-18': 71042900, '2020-12-21': 76729100, '2020-12-22': 66033100, '2020-12-23': 58772200, '2020-12-24': 26306800, '2020-12-28': 55878700, '2020-12-29': 47302400, '2020-12-30': 34586700, '2020-12-31': 39922500, '2021-01-04': 44970400, '2021-01-05': 29050400, '2021-01-06': 32732900, '2021-01-07': 32240000, '2021-01-08': 41313800, '2021-01-11': 32609000, '2021-01-12': 26995000, '2021-01-13': 51216600, '2021-01-14': 32908000, '2021-01-15': 92285500, '2021-01-19': 48675800, '2021-01-20': 37459000, '2021-01-21': 29891400, '2021-01-22': 156844700, '2021-01-25': 191345300, '2021-01-26': 65870000, '2021-01-27': 170758800, '2021-01-28': 85250700, '2021-01-29': 42030900, '2021-02-01': 43460900, '2021-02-02': 69647900, '2021-02-03': 35312000, '2021-02-04': 31565000, '2021-02-05': 62230800, '2021-02-08': 72376000, '2021-02-09': 44243200, '2021-02-10': 45177200, '2021-02-11': 51863200, '2021-02-12': 60359100, '2021-02-16': 180294300, '2021-02-17': 151007000, '2021-02-18': 313175100, '2021-02-19': 320063700, '2021-02-22': 183049500, '2021-02-23': 145289400, '2021-02-24': 90095700, '2021-02-25': 161776400, '2021-02-26': 119588600, '2021-03-01': 84352800, '2021-03-02': 73539700, '2021-03-03': 76548900, '2021-03-04': 160436400, '2021-03-05': 172875900, '2021-03-08': 93973900, '2021-03-09': 99106800, '2021-03-10': 102847800, '2021-03-11': 84337000, '2021-03-12': 58489200, '2021-03-15': 56101500, '2021-03-16': 72869300, '2021-03-17': 76465400, '2021-03-18': 57141400, '2021-03-19': 57611900, '2021-03-22': 46208100, '2021-03-23': 50169700, '2021-03-24': 68755400, '2021-03-25': 36454703}

## I've tried utilizing a code from an archived answer but I have been unsuccessful.
dict((k, dict[k]) for k in (val_1, val_2, val_3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comprehension

```py
{k: v for k, v in date_vol_dict.items() if v in values_of_interest_list}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary comprehension:

```
date_vol_dict = {'2020-09-30': 338584400, ...
values_of_interest_list = [338584400, 124297600, ...

interesting_date_vol = {date: vol for date, vol in date_vol_dict.items() if vol in values_of_interest_list}

print(interesting_date_vol)
```

Output:

```
{'2020-09-30': 338584400, '2020-10-01': 124297600, '2020-10-02': 55018300, '2020-10-05': 36316900, '2020-10-08': 34989200, '2020-10-09': 19653500, '2020-10-14': 13652600, '2020-10-15': 12924100, '2020-10-16': 11142500, '2020-10-19': 9126400}
```

Comment: Amazing, this worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Just curious how did you determine segment 1 of the interesting_date_vol dictionary? ```    
   date: vol for date

Comment: Standard dict comprehension syntax: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary-comprehension

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dict comprehension to check each value, and keep the item pair if that value is contained in your list.

```
>>> {k:v for k,v in date_vol_dict.items() if v in values_of_interest_list}
{'2020-09-30': 338584400, '2020-10-01': 124297600, '2020-10-02': 55018300, '2020-10-05': 36316900, '2020-10-08': 34989200, '2020-10-09': 19653500, '2020-10-14': 13652600, '2020-10-15': 12924100, '2020-10-16': 11142500, '2020-10-19': 9126400}
```